# How to register ajaxified update inside another one

Tags: asp.net, telerik, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I want to put  inside  and a button inside it, When I press the button I need to do ajax post inside  only not ..
Structure will be something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="parentUpdatePanel">
  <asp:panel id="subPanel">
    <button id="btnAjax">
  </asp:panel>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Using Telerik controls I used to do this:

```
protected override void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e){
   RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(this).AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(subPanel, subPanel);
}
```

How can I do it using ScriptManager from ASP.NET toolbox controls?

Tanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest update panels like that. Remove either the RadAjaxManager setting, or the  asp:UpdatePanel.

Anyway, you can try making use of the UpdateMode=Conditional setting like this. Add anytning more complex and I don't know what may break. If the paren update panel happens to dispose it is very likely to start throwing JS erros because the child update panel will not be found.

I think you would be better off with just the parent update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Updatepanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="I will not be part of the inner update" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Updatepanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text="I will be updated" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="partial postback" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and server code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```